# This function sends the to GPU for calculation?

Tags: c, cuda

```
__host__ void generateVector(int count) {

    A = new int[count];
    B = new int[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        A[i] = rand_from_0_to_100_gen();
        B[i] = rand_from_0_to_100_gen();
    }
}
```

i created array in CPU side and with this function i try to sum those two arrays :

```
__host__  void vectorSum(const int *dA, const int* dB, int count,  int* dC){

    cudaMalloc((void**) &dA, count * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dB, count * sizeof(int));


    cudaMemcpy(A, dA , count * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(B, dA , count * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int tid = 0;

    while(tid < count){
        tid++;
        dC[tid] = dA[tid] + dB[tid];

    }

    cout << "C: {";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            cout << dC[i];
            cout << ",";
        }
        cout << "}";
}
```

Do i make this calculation on GPU or CPU. I doubt about that.

Secondly, i call this function in main like that:

```
vectorSum(dA,dB,numOfData,dC);
```

but says dC is used before its value set. Why? what do i have to set before calculation.

whole code:

```
using namespace std;
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *A;
int *B;

int rand_from_0_to_100_gen(void) {
    return rand() % 100;
}

__host__ void generateVector(int count) {

    A = new int[count];
    B = new int[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        A[i] = rand_from_0_to_100_gen();
        B[i] = rand_from_0_to_100_gen();
    }
}

__host__ void displayVector(int count) {
    generateVector(count);

    cout << "A: {";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << A[i];
        cout << ",";
    }
    cout << "}";


    cout << "\n";

    cout << "B: {";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << B[i];
        cout << ",";
    }
    cout << "}";
}

__host__  void vectorSum(const int *dA, const int* dB, int count,  int* dC){

    cudaMalloc((void**) &dA, count * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dB, count * sizeof(int));


    cudaMemcpy(A, dA , count * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(B, dB , count * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int tid = 0;

    while(tid < count){
        tid++;
        dC[tid] = dA[tid] + dB[tid];

    }


    cout << "C: {";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            cout << dC[i];
            cout << ",";
        }
        cout << "}";
}

__host__ void vectorDiff(const int *dA, const int* dB, int count, int* dC){



}



int main(void) {

    int dev, numOfData;
    const int *dA;
    const int *dB;
    int *dC;

    cudaGetDevice(&dev);
    cout << "Device with ID " << dev << " is defined\n";



    cout << "Please enter the number of data:";
    cin >> numOfData;
    displayVector(numOfData);
    vectorSum(dA,dB,numOfData,dC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have another global variable A and B besides the ones declared in `generateVector`? Because otherwise the `CudaMemcpy` in `vectorsum` is not going to work. About `dC`, are you sure you have allocated that memory? Provide the whole code and we might be of more help.

Comment: Take a look at the Nvidia example, it does what you want and it will be a good example to learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to start with the examples from [Nvidia](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html), they have an example doing vector addition. [Here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/C/Projects/x64/vectorAdd.tar.gz) is the direct link to the code.

As for your code, some pointers about stuff that is not right in your code.

If you want to use Cuda you will want to execute `vectorSum` on the GPU, but before doing that you need to fix some things on your program.

`vectorSum` will be a kernel function for Cuda and it will be executed on the GPU, so you will have to use the qualifier `__global__` instead of `__host__`.

You will need to allocate the memory on the GPU to hold both vectors content **and its result (where is the CudaMalloc for dC?)**. You need to allocate and copy the memory from the host, so both `CudaMalloc` and `CudaMemcpy` should be done on the host, in `main` for example. You will also need to copy back the results to main memory with `CudaMemcpy` but with direction `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost`.

Finally, you can't call a kernel function like that, you will need something looking like this `vectorSum<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dA,dB,numOfData,dC);` with `dimGrid` being the dimension of the Cuda grid and `dimBlock` being the dimension of the Cuda block.

Comment: when i execute cudaMemcpy in __global__ vectorSum i get the error: calling a host function from global is not allowed

Comment: Of course you can't, you can't allocate GPU memory from the GPU itself. I explain that in my answer, CudaMalloc and CudaMemcpy should be executed on the host, hence not in the `vectorSum` function. Please, take a look at the code from Nvidia, it is the file named vectorAdd.cu inside the package.